# No deployment options Conjure-up ubuntu 16.04LTS

Tags: openstack, cloud, conjure-up

I'm new for openstack and conjure-up. I followed the instructions below: https://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/try-openstack.

However, after I run `conjure-up` and click <kbd>OpenStack with NovaLXD</kbd>, I saw the screen below:

[image: "Choose a cloud" dialog]

All options are gray so I cannot choose any of them.

I searched online and I saw this similar but not same post: [Conjure Up : Unable to deploy OpenStack Cloud on LXD Configuration Ubuntu 16.04LTS (LXD not found)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/955728/conjure-up-unable-to-deploy-openstack-cloud-on-lxd-configuration-ubuntu-16-04l)

However, the solution of this post didn't work for me.
Any suggestions will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should install and initiate LXD.

Run these commands as described in [this documentation for conjure up](https://docs.conjure-up.io/2.4.0/en/):

```
sudo snap install lxd
/snap/bin/lxd init
```

The localhost option will be green in the **Configure a cloud** section when LXD was initiated

Comment: Hi Vahid, thank you for your reply. Actually I've tried these commands you suggested but none of them work on my situation.

Comment: Can you launch container with LXD? I want to make sure your LXD doesn't have any problem. Please run `\snap\bin\lxc launch ubuntu:16.04`

Comment: Thank you again! Vahid. I used the mixed solution from the post I posted above(Conjure Up : Unable to deploy OpenStack Cloud on LXD Configuration Ubuntu 16.04LTS (LXD not found) ) to resolve this issue.